# PostgreSQL error using JDBC

Tags: android, postgresql, jdbc

I am getting an error trying to connect to a postgresql database through an android project.

The error is "Caused by: java.lang.VerifyError: org/postgresql/jdbc/TimestampUtils"

I could not figure out what caused this at all.

Here is the entire error:

```
> java.lang.RuntimeException: An error occured while executing
> doInBackground()
>                                                                                            at android.os.AsyncTask$3.done(AsyncTask.java:300)                    
> at
> java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.finishCompletion(FutureTask.java:355) 
> at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.setException(FutureTask.java:222)  
> at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.run(FutureTask.java:242)           
> at android.os.AsyncTask$SerialExecutor$1.run(AsyncTask.java:231)      
> at
> java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1112)
> at
> java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:587)
> at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:841)                              
> Caused by: java.lang.VerifyError: org/postgresql/jdbc/TimestampUtils  
> at org.postgresql.jdbc.PgConnection.<init>(PgConnection.java:279)     
> at org.postgresql.Driver.makeConnection(Driver.java:431)              
> at org.postgresql.Driver.connect(Driver.java:247)                     
> at java.sql.DriverManager.getConnection(DriverManager.java:179)       
> at
> com.alfordmedia.ryanorourke.inventory.Inventory$Conn.doInBackground(Inventory.java:88)
> at
> com.alfordmedia.ryanorourke.inventory.Inventory$Conn.doInBackground(Inventory.java:78)
> at android.os.AsyncTask$2.call(AsyncTask.java:288)                    
> at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.run(FutureTask.java:237)           
> at android.os.AsyncTask$SerialExecutor$1.run(AsyncTask.java:231)      
> at
> java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1112) 
> at
> java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:587) 
> at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:841)
```

Here is my code:

```
private class Conn extends AsyncTask<Void, Void, Void>
    {
        @Override
        protected Void doInBackground(Void... params)
        {
            Properties props = new Properties();
            String url = "jdbc:postgresql://hostname/database";
            props.setProperty("user","user");
            props.setProperty("password","pass");
            props.setProperty("ssl","true");
            try
            {
                Connection db = DriverManager.getConnection(url,props);
            }
            catch (SQLException e)
            {
                e.printStackTrace();
            }
            return null;
        }
        @Override
        protected void onPostExecute(Void result)
        {
            super.onPostExecute(result);
        }
    }
```

Comment: Exactly which variant and version of the JDBC driver are you using?. Using JDBC drivers from android (or more specifically: trying to access remote databases), is not a very good idea, you are probably better off using a REST service as a go between..

Comment: 42.0.0. I am only going to be on the network the database is connected to when i connect to it. Would you still recommend using a middleman?

Comment: But are you using the JDBC 4 (Java 6), JDBC 4.1 (Java 7) or JDBC 4.2 (Java 8) variant? Keep in mind that JDBC drivers are developed with the intent of being used from 'real' Java, not from Android, that may lead to issues.

Comment: Makes sense, do you have a suggestion for a better way to go about this? I'd really like to connect straight through as there are no security risks with what i am using this for.